# Visual Studio 2017 - Access Denied Error on Rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-2017, build-error

I have a solution I created in Visual Studio 2017. All solution files are stored on a network location, accessed via a mapped drive. Up until earlier this week (April 10, 2018), everything worked fine. I could perform all required functionality.

Now, when I attempt to debug or build the release files, I get the following error:

***Unable to copy file "obj\x64\Release\program.exe" to "bin\x64\Release\program.exe". Access to the path 'bin\x64\Release\program.exe' is denied.***

The file is completely locked at this point. I can't do anything with it. I've done all of these suggestions found in other posts:

- Make sure all instances of VBCSCompiler.exe are killed
- Install the latest version of VS 2017
- Install version 1.0.8 of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

None of it works. I still get the error.

Now the real strangeness...

After I rebooted my machine the .exe file is removed from the release and debug folders. I can open the solution and rebuild the project successfully at that point, complete with a new, fully accessible .exe file. If I attempt to rebuild right away, with no changes made, the error shows up again.

I have to reboot my machine to release this file. That's hardly efficient.

If I copy the solution locally everything works fine. I don't have any issues.

I'm willing to move to working locally (as I'm sure it's a more advisable approach, but please spare me lectures on that topic)  but I'd like to get to the bottom of this, if possible.

Thanks for any help you can offer...

Comment: Probably not a permanent solution, but if you take the read only flag off the target folder, you should be able to build it.

Comment: One more thing, if I change to "Any CPU" platform in my configs, I do not get the error. It writes to **'bin\Release\program.exe'** as expected.This seems to be an issue with compiling a x64 instance of the .exe to a network location.